# Comparing Elements in Array [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

i would like to ask, how to compare all elements in the array to get the BIG int and then display it..

heres the code..

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class compare {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int num[]=new int[10];

    for(int x=0;x<num.length;x++){
        num[x]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter"));
    }

    for(int c=0;c<num.length;c++){
        if(num[c]>num[c])
        {

        }

    }



    }

}
```

now, heres my new code.

but, it does not compare the inputted nums

```
for(int c=0;c<num.length;c++){
        if(num[c]>num[c])
        {
            int large=num[c];
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the largest num "+large);
        }
```

Comment: Do you want the maximum `int`?

Comment: Go try it out, write some code and then come back with a specific question when you are stuck.

Comment: `if(num[c]>num[c])` This will check elements to itself.

Comment: @Smit what is the rayt code for comparing these??

Comment: @jarnthrax YOu have to write that code. Look for answers given to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.

```
if(num[c] > num[c])
```

will check the value at position `c` with itself and will always be false. You need to compare  the value of `num[c]` with the highest value you have seen so far.

```
int large = num[c];
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the largest num "+large);
```

You declare `large` within the loop, meaning that for each iteration (where you enter the if-condition, which you do not, but let's say you did) you declare and assign a *new* variable called `large` and assign it the value of `num[c]`. The dialog is also showed from within the loop, which could cause it to be shown many times for different values.

So you need a variable that will hold the maximum value we have seen so far and use this variable in the loop:

```
int max = num[0]; 
for(int c = 1; c < num.length; c++) { 
    if(max < num[c]) {
        max = num[c];
    }
}
```

Since `max` is equal to the value at index 0 in `num` I can start the loop from index 1.
Please try to understand *how* and *why* this works.

When this is done, you have the maximum value from `num` in the `max` variable and you can display your dialog.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the largest num " + max);
```

Comment: ahmf, why c is equal to 1?

Comment: @jarnthrax You can set it to 0 and it will work just fine. I do it because, when I enter the loop, `max` is already equal to the first value in `num`, hence I do not need to compare it with the first value . Try to go through what happens step by step (maybe write values down on a piece of paper) and try to understand what happens and why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the biggest one you have found so far, because you need to compare everything else to this.

So do something like;

```
int biggest = 0;
for(int c=0;c<num.length;c++){
        if(//Some conditional)
        {
            biggest = //Something
        }
    }
```

I think you should figure out what goes in the spots I have comments.

Comment: If `num` only contain negative values, you will get the wrong result regardless of what he replaces your comments with.

Comment: True, but then what is "biggest"? Biggest by absolute value? Biggest by linear ordering? I made the assumption that they were non-negative because this was not clarified.